# Shorten static definitions

Tags: c++, class, namespaces, scope

If I have a class named `SomeClassName`, can I avoid writing `SomeClassName::` everytime I am referring to something in that class? I am thinking along the lines of namespace where I can enclose the definitions in `using MyNamespace { ... };` and avoid writing the namespace the class is under every time (bad practice?).

One of the reasons is that now I have code like this, which is quite long and hard to read imo:

```
SomeClassName::SimpleStruct SomeClassName::m_someTable[SomeClassName::m_someTableSize][SomeClassName::m_someTableSize] = {SomeClassName::EmptyStruct};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using-directive class static functions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6083184/using-directive-class-static-functions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, but you can shorten the name with a typedef, if all you are after is less typing:

```
typedef SomeClassName SCN;
```

Comment: Does this work in the specific case outlined in the question, defining a static variable declared in the class? I don't think it does.

Comment: @Mark It does for a simple case, but I have not managed to understand/replicate the example give by OP.

Answer (score 1):

Just use global types/enums instead.

Answer (score 1):

You unfortunately have to fully-qualify identifier names with the `::` scope resolution operator when referring to an identifier inside of another namespace/scope (classes define a scope as well), and the `using` directive only works with namesapaces.  The only other option would be to use `typedefs` like John mentioned, or possibly macros.  If you didn't have this restriction, then you would end up with identifier name conflicts all over the place, and would end up with C-style naming conventions where function names can get very long because they basically put the namespace into the function/identifier name.